# How to restrict access to users on Tomcat manager

Tags: tomcat9

How to restrict access to users for Tomcat manager. Basically I want to create a user who will have only read access to the manager application and not be able to deploy/undelpoy apps.

Regards,
Ashwini

Comment: I tried to create a new user in tomcat-users.xml with admin-gui,manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx assigning 1 role at a time. But this resulted in full access like Start/Stop/Undeploy/Deploy to the users.

I am not sure how to give them just read access to Tomcat manager. Could someone please add your inputs if anyone has tried this?

Comment: Another update is I tried to change the owner of the webapps to root. This worked ( does not allow us to undeploy apps from GUI). But does not allow us to deploy as well.

This way we can restrict the developers from changing/deleting. But blocks us as well from performing deployments.